Realm syncEnabled for Android Studio app Java
I am having trouble with the following in my build.gradle(app):
realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

I keep getting an error saying that syncEnabled is private.
I have tried import and adding dependencies and plugins in the project level but I am not sure what to do now.
